# Images on Card position

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am modifying the following [guideline](https://www.cssscript.com/polaroid-like-stacked-image-slideshow/) by putting the images inside the bootstrap card.
However the result is the images looks like floating.

[image]

Please advise how make it fit in the card?

Here is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/agt2021/51yLn03g/4/)

```
<div class="card" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5><b>Image</b></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">

<div class='images'> <img class='image' src='https://unsplash.it/400/380/?random'> <img class='image' src='https://unsplash.it/400/410/?random'> <img class='image' src='https://unsplash.it/400/390/?random'> <img class='image' src='https://unsplash.it/405/410/?random'> <img class='image' src='https://unsplash.it/400/425/?random'> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the elements inside the div are `absolute` positioned (`.image`), there is no height for the child items, just define the height explicitly on the parent (`.images`).

css

```
images { 
    cursor: pointer; 
    min-height:300px; /* changed here! */
}
```

```js
(function() {
  var cssTransition, imageOffset, imageWidth, images, queue, timeout, touch;

  cssTransition = function() {
    var body, i, len, style, vendor, vendors;
    body = document.body || document.documentElement;
    style = body.style;
    vendors = ['Moz', 'Webkit', 'O'];
    if (typeof style['transition'] === 'string') {
      return true;
    }
    for (i = 0, len = vendors.length; i < len; i++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)){break;}
      vendor = vendors[i];
      if (typeof style[vendor + 'Transition'] === 'string') {
        return true;
      }
    }
window.CP.exitedLoop(1);

    return false;
  };

  queue = false;

  touch = document.documentElement['ontouchstart'] !== void 0;

  images = document.querySelector('.images');

  imageWidth = images.firstElementChild.offsetWidth;

  imageOffset = images.firstElementChild.offsetLeft;

  timeout = cssTransition() ? [300, 400] : [0, 0];

  images.addEventListener((touch ? 'touchend' : 'click'), function(event) {
    var direction, lastClassList;
    if (queue) {
      return;
    }
    queue = true;
    if (((touch ? event.changedTouches[0].pageX : event.pageX) - imageOffset) > imageWidth / 2) {
      direction = 'slide-right';
    } else {
      direction = 'slide-left';
    }
    lastClassList = images.lastElementChild.classList;
    lastClassList.add(direction);
    return setTimeout(function() {
      lastClassList.remove(direction);
      lastClassList.add('back');
      return setTimeout(function() {
        images.insertBefore(images.lastElementChild, images.firstElementChild);
        lastClassList.remove('back');
        return queue = false;
      }, timeout[0]);
    }, timeout[1]);
  }, false);

}).call(this);
```

```css
.images { cursor: pointer; min-height:300px; }

.images:hover .image:nth-child(4) {
  -moz-transform: rotate(10deg) translateX(50px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(10deg) translateX(50px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg) translateX(50px);
  transform: rotate(10deg) translateX(50px);
}

.images:hover .image:nth-child(3) {
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg) translateX(75px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg) translateX(75px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg) translateX(75px);
  transform: rotate(3deg) translateX(75px);
}

.images:hover .image:nth-child(2) {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg) translateX(-50px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg) translateX(-50px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg) translateX(-50px);
  transform: rotate(-2deg) translateX(-50px);
}

.images:hover .image:first-child {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg) translateX(-75px) translateY(-10px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-8deg) translateX(-75px) translateY(-10px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg) translateX(-75px) translateY(-10px);
  transform: rotate(-8deg) translateX(-75px) translateY(-10px);
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: -110px;
  margin-left: -105px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-bottom-width: 15px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.25);
  z-index: 2;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.image:first-child {
  -moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
}

.image:nth-child(2) {
  -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
  transform: rotate(2deg);
}

.image:nth-child(3) {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.image:nth-child(4) {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.image:last-child {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}

.image.slide-right {
  -moz-transform: rotate(290deg) translateX(250px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(290deg) translateX(250px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(290deg) translateX(250px);
  transform: rotate(290deg) translateX(250px);
}

.image.slide-left {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-290deg) translateX(-250px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-290deg) translateX(-250px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-290deg) translateX(-250px);
  transform: rotate(-290deg) translateX(-250px);
}

.image.back { z-index: 1; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card" style="width:100%">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h5><b>Image</b></h5>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">

    <div class='images'> <img class='image' src='https://unsplash.it/400/380/?random'> <img class='image' src='https://unsplash.it/400/410/?random'> <img class='image' src='https://unsplash.it/400/390/?random'> <img class='image' src='https://unsplash.it/405/410/?random'> <img class='image' src='https://unsplash.it/400/425/?random'> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```